# Principal component analysis with factor loading restrictions

Tags: r, variance, pca

I'm interested in comparing the variance explained by the first principle component with a similar one that has factors loading values are specified.  For example, using the Iris data in R, say I wanted to compare PC1 (below) with the variance explained by setting the factor loading values equal to [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]. How do I do that?

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

iris <-  iris %>% select(-Species)
AlternateLoadings = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1)
irisPCA4 <- prcomp(iris)
irisPCA4

Standard deviations (1, .., p=4):
[1] 2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862

Rotation (n x k) = (4 x 4):
                     PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574

summary(irisPCA4)

Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2    PC3     PC4
Standard deviation     2.0563 0.49262 0.2797 0.15439
Proportion of Variance 0.9246 0.05307 0.0171 0.00521
Cumulative Proportion  0.9246 0.97769 0.9948 1.00000
```

More generally, how does one constrain some or all of the PCA factor loading values in a PCA when estimating the principle components?

Comment: Your two questions seem to be unrelated to one another. Variance explained by a component equals its sum of squared loadings (it's for your Q1). As for your Q2 about "constrained loadings" - I could not understand it. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: As I understand it, the first PCA sets the factor loadings to maximize the variance that can be explained by the first PC. But sometimes an alternative factor loading is more intuitive (say setting all the loadings to -1, 0, or 1). I'd like to compare the results of doing that with the PCA way of finding PC1. The second question is a generalization because it involves restricting some of the variable loadings but not all of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "setting" the loadings? PCA does not allow arbitrary setting of its loadings given a specific dataset which its analyzes. PCA is the eigendecomposition of covariance (or correlation) matrix computed from the data.

Comment: It sounds like you might be searching for *factor analysis.*

Comment: @ttnphns, it certainly seems like loading restrictions within PCA are possible. R modules like nsprcomp (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nsprcomp/index.html) let you perform  constrained principal component analysis with non-negativity and/or sparsity constraints. I don't want those particular restrictions, but it certainly seems like there are PCA methods that provide at least some constraints on the PCA factor loadings.

Comment: This what you link to is from the domain of sparse or constrained PCA, which has gone _far_ beyond the classic PCA. The documentation says it uses iterative EM algorithm and the principle axes produced are _not_ classic, orthogonal eigenvectors. I'm new to their complex technique so can't help you. By all acconts your question is not a classic PCA question.